# О способе проверки запятой путем перестановки придаточного предложения

Tags: запятые, союзы, спп

Этот способ Розенталь использует в теме "**Запятая на стыке двух союзов в сложном предложении** (обычно встречаются два подчинительных или сочинительный и подчинительный союзы). Также он говорит о встрече присоединительного (сочинительного) и подчинительного союзов.

Этот метод у Розенталя касается еще каких-то тем?

Меня удивляет, что Грамота.ру использует его в предложении: *Поэтому, если я допущу ошибку, меня выгонят с работы*. http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=201844

Даже если назвать наречие "поэтому" союзом или еще чем-то, то его следует отнести к присоединительным союзам? Или как?

Comment: И тишина да будет вам ответом...

Comment: Вот на это я и рассчитывала, мой проницательный читатель.  Это вопрос, обращенный к вашему сознанию или подсознанию в дальнейшем, когда вы все задачи в правописании будете решать  методом перестановки, "незаконно" расширенным до вселенских масштабов. И это обращение к нашим будущим пользователям русского языка, более просвещенным и лучше мыслящим, чем мы.

Comment: У Розенталя, кстати, в первом же пункте параграфа 36 (old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140) имеется пример с союзным словом: *Горничная была сирота, которая, чтобы кормиться, должна была поступить в услужение (Л. Т.) — запятая разделяет союзное слово и подчинительный союз.*

Comment: А чем вам союзное слово "которая" не угодило? У него статус основного союзного средства, как и у союза. А вот "поэтому" –  это вообще слово-загадка, его здесь уж лет семь обсуждают. Также БСП, ССП и СПП при наличии этого слова различить ну никак не могут. Что ж делать, проницательности не хватает...

Comment: Перестановка либо **изъятие**. Порой только одно работает (было дело).